# Colorize Point Instance from texture _ Geometry Nodes_

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working on 3d carpets assets with Blender, i'm using Geometry Nodes for scattering the fur.
I wish colorize the instances with the pixel color on my "emiter" shader difuse texture.
We can do it simple with Hair systhem, but with GN it look complex for my GN skill 
Anybody can help me ?

My actual GN graph:
[image]

My curent result:
[image]

Wat i wish. (using Hair systhem)
[image]

Comment: Same question in this thread :
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213224/control-instance-color-with-geometry-nodes

Comment: Thkx Gordon.
Yes it is !