# Geometry nodes Can I paint every instant of the house with a clear division of color in a circle?

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

This thread is what I need [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213224/control-instance-color-with-geometry-nodes), but here the blender version is lower than 3.0 and I don't quite know how to come to the same. (I tried throwing stuff on buildings (B1, B2..), but it didn't work out as expected.
[image]

My geoNodes
[image]

How do I just paint the city into zones ? I don't even need a lot of flexibility.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object info is a suitable node. All you have to do is just calculate a distance between the node and center point.

For that, you can use a **Vector Math** node with a **Distance** mode:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that it works even if the instances are part of the same object ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, but only if they are not realized. In this case, they are objects inside the object

Comment: @Gorgious, Thanks works almost perfectly, except for this [building](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-2feef6ca14.gif), for some reason... but ok

Comment: I don't have access to the file

Comment: @Crantisz, edddited

Comment: Connection timeout this time :-)

Comment: @Crantisz, my goood uff  https://gifyu.com/image/Szmjr

Comment: @DeoneaseDistortions Nope

Comment: @Crantisz I can see the files... weird.

Comment: @Crantisz, JeSuS Chrizt  Enjoy :)
https://en.wmpics.pics/pm-GIOH.html
https://yapx.ru/v/QjSGz
https://tenor.com/bQntC.gif
https://en.wmpics.pics/pm-GIOH.html
https://tenor.com/bQntC.gif
https://yapx.ru/v/QjSGz
https://yapx.ru/v/QjSGz
https://tenor.com/bQntC.gif
https://tenor.com/bQntC.gif
https://yapx.ru/v/QjSGz

Comment: Yes, it's looks like that the center of tall building is high, so distance to them from world center also is big. So if you make your building with object origin on the bottom face it will not be an issue